# Is there any way to translate XML contents?

Tags: xml, localization, translation, google-translate

I have the following XML format:

```
<Opinions>
  <Opinion target="الغرفة" category="ROOMS#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="5" to="11"/>
  <Opinion target="الموظفون" category="SERVICE#GENERAL" polarity="positive" from="25" to="33"/>
  <Opinion target="بوفيه الإفطار" category="FOOD_DRINKS#QUALITY" polarity="positive" from="35" to="48"/>
  <Opinion target="وجبة العشاء" category="FOOD_DRINKS#PRICES" polarity="negative" from="67" to="78"/>
</Opinions>
```

Is there any way to translate the Arabic part into English?

Comment: The "attranslate" tool is specifically designed to translate XML-contents like this. You can google "attranslate" or find it on npm.

Answer (score -1):

If this is all, translate it by hand or use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en) or another translation service.

If you want to automate it, you can parse out the Arabic, send it to the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate) or another translating API, and then put in the English the API returns. This requires some XML manipulation, but nothing all that complex.

There are dedicated XML localisation/translation tools around, but as far as I know they don't do the actual translating, they just make the process more easy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually the file is a lot bigger and I have tried a lot of automated programs without any success but I as I see it I have no solution but to do it manually

Comment: Or program it manually 8-). It would involve something like parsing out the Arabic terms to list, have the list translated by Google, and use XSLT or something else to put the translated terms back into the XML. Not something I would do for a one-off. Please vote for my answer if you are so inclined. It already has a "vote", but still.